# How is this zip command being used in perl?

Tags: perl, zip

I found this piece of code in perl

```
system("zip $ZIP_DEBUG -r -9 itvlib.zip $include $exclude");
```

However I don't understand how it is working. I mean system() is used to fire 'system' commands right ? So is this 'zip' command used here a 'system' command ? 
But I tried firing just the following on the command prompt;

```
zip $ZIP_DEBUG -r -9 itvlib.zip arg1 arg2
```

It didn't work !
it gave the following error:

```
'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Well this shouldn't have happened, since the command seems to use 'zip' as a system command. So this makes the command 'zip' *mysterious*

Can you please help me to understand this command with all its parameters?

Comment: What didn't work from the command line? It would help to know. Also, the values of `$include` and `$exclude` are interpolated when that line is executed; what values did they have in the program? (P.S. I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: Sorry sir, Now I have edited the question appropriately.

Comment: @drunkMonk For future reference, "it didn't work!" is not a very adequate problem description. What didn't work? Didn't the command exist? What error messages did you get?

Comment: @TLP I have edited the question like you suggested ..

Comment: @drunkMonk Well, it would seem you are using a Windows system. `zip` (probably) refers to a linux command. That is the problem with relying on system calls.

Comment: @TLP but it is actually *able* to zip the files ! thats the most *ironic* thing.

Comment: @drunkMonk Hard to say without seeing the code, but there might be other code/modules that facilitate zipping in Windows.

Comment: @TLP actually its simply using the zip exe in the windows system :) (from the answer that i accepted)

Comment: @drunkMonk See how easy it got when you didn't use "it didn't work!"? =)

Comment: ya .. thanks. I shall keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
system("zip $ZIP_DEBUG -r -9 itvlib.zip $include $exclude");
```

is running a program named `zip` (probably `zip.exe`) somewhere on the path.  `$ZIP_DEBUG`, `$include`, and `$exclude` are Perl variables that are interpolated into the command line before the command is run.

If the `system` call works in the Perl script, but `zip -?` gives the `'zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file` error, then the PATH of the Perl script must be different than the PATH in your command prompt.  Or, there might be a `zip` command in the current directory when Perl executes the `system` command.  (In Windows, the current directory is an implicit member of your PATH.)

To see what the PATH is for the Perl script, you can add a `print "$ENV{PATH}\n";` before the system command.  To see what the PATH is in your command prompt, type `PATH`.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably not working since you're not replacing things like `$ZIP_DEBUG` with their equivalent *real* values. Within Perl, they will be replaced with the values of the variables *before* being passed to the `system` call.

If you print out those Perl variables (or even the entire command) before you execute that `system` call, you'll find out those real values that you need to use. You can use the following transcript to guide you:

```
$ perl -e '
>     $ZIP_DEBUG = "xyzzy";
>     $include = "inc_files";
>     $exclude = "exc_files";
>     print "zip $ZIP_DEBUG -r -9 itvlib.zip $include $exclude";
> '
zip xyzzy -r -9 itvlib.zip inc_files exc_files
```

For details on how `system` works, see [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html). For details on what `zip` needs to function, you should just be able to run:

```
man zip
```

from a command line shell (assuming you're on Linux or its brethren). If, instead, you're on a different operating system (like Windows), you'll have to figure out how to get the zip options out. This *may* well be as simple as `zip -?` of `zip -h` but there's no guarantee that will work.

If it's the same as the Info-ZIP `zip` under Linux (and it may be if you have the `-9` and `-r` options and your `exclude` variable starts with `-x`), then `zip -h` will get you basic help and `zip -h2` will give you a lot more.

Comment: exactly sir, zip -? or zip -h doesn't work. I just wish to see the gory details of this zip command which has been used here, i am looking where i can find it.

Comment: @drunkMonk, that depends entirely on who made it. If `zip -?` (or other variants) don't work, try `zip` without any arguments. The default may be to offer help, or at least show how you can get help. Failing that, find the documentation for your particular `zip` program. I'm pretty certain it doesn't come standard with Windows so you must have gotten it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `zip` is a system command. The variables `$ZIP_DEBUG` and such are perl variables that are interpolated to the command before launching `zip`.

To debug what the actual call is, try adding:

```
print("zip $ZIP_DEBUG -r -9 itvlib.zip $include $exclude\n");
```

See [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for details on `system`.